# Crear fichero de logs en xamarin forms para aplicación multiplataforma

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, archivo, xamarin.forms, error404

estoy tratando de añadir una forma de deputar los fallos que se den en mi aplicación multiplataforma desarrollada en xamarin forms.

Al depurar en visual studio es fácil ver donde se encuentras los errores, o donde saltan las excepciones ya que la consola te da la información a cerca de ello, pero ahora el siguiente paso el archivar la aplicación y ejecutarla en un móvil Android o en un ordenador con Windows 10 a fin de probarla a fondo. Aquí es donde viene el problema ya que cuando salta un error en plena ejecución únicamente obtienes el mensaje de que surgió un problema y se cierra la aplicación o se cierra la aplicación directamente sin previo aviso.

Conocéis algún método mas eficaz que crear un fichero a mano y escribirlo cada poco para que pueda crear un log en cada plataforma con cada ejecución de la aplicación?

Muchas gracias de antemano, ojala alguien sepa de alguna posible solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que uses alguna plataforma que te permita gestionar errores. A mi personalmente me gusta mucho https://appcenter.ms/

Das de alta en la web tu aplicación y te da una ID, bajas su sdk y pones la ID y en cuanto se use la aplicación empezara a recopilar información.

Sin que hagas nada más ya te dira información de uso (cantidad de usuarios, duración de sesiones, dispositivos, version, etc...) y ademas te dara un registro de excepciones no controladas.

Ademas puedes añadir tu tanto control de excepciones como de eventos concretos (los eventos los puedes ver en tiempo real).

Esa plataforma tambien te permite desplegar a usuarios en pruebas (sin pasar por la store) y probar notificaciones push.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS, Voy a mirar un poco como funciona y a lo mejor mañana o esta tarde pruebo a añadirlo si no veo otra solución. Porque si te registra todo eso me vendría genial

Comment: Hay que añadir para tema de excepciones o errores algo más a parte de los dos using y la linea de onStart con el id de la app que me dice en el código de app?

Comment: Si @MarcosMuñozMorales, `Crashes.TrackError(exception);` para excepciones que uno mismo ha manejado pero quiere trackear.

Comment: Te vas a enamorar de https://appcenter.ms :D

Comment: Y si salta una excepción que no tenga controlada como la registro?

Comment: O no hay modo de ello? solo por curiosidad ya que lo mas útil seria las no controladas no?

Comment: Si salta una excepcion no controlada tambien te la registra, y te pone el mensaje de la excepcion como si estuvieras debugando, linea donde dio, esas cosas

Comment: De momento solo me ha registrado los inicios de la aplicación y nada más, cuando le doy a eventos o errores me sale como añadirlo, cosa que ya realice, imagino que quizás eso es debido a que nos e ha producido ninguno. Aunque no se si esq no lo he activado